# use EDD Content Restriction for restricting php in template

Tags: plugins, themes, templates

edd restrict content plugin creates this shortcodes and these are working in pages and posts :

```
[edd_restrict id="any"]sample restricted html or text[/edd_restrict]
```

but i want to use it in my theme not in the posts or pages. i tried this :

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[edd_restrict id="any"]' sample php '[/edd_restrict]' );?>
```

but theme shows me fatal error. so how can i use this shortcodes in wordress theme? sample text here will be a php code that i want to restrict.

want to put the line below between those shortcodes in my single.php in wordpress :

```
<li><?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'download',true)!= ""){echo "<a href='".get_post_meta($post->ID, 'download',true)."' > دانلود با لینک مستقیم</a> ";} else { echo ""; } ?>
<?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'download32',true)!= ""){echo "<a href='".get_post_meta($post->ID, 'download32',true)."'>لینک مستقیم نسخه 32bit / </a> ";} else { echo ""; } ?> 
<?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'download64',true)!= ""){echo "<a href='".get_post_meta($post->ID, 'download64',true)."'>لینک مستقیم نسخه 64bit </a> ";} else { echo ""; } ?>
<?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'downloadwin',true)!= ""){echo "<a href='".get_post_meta($post->ID, 'downloadwin',true)."'>دانلود نسخه ویندوز  </a> ";} else { echo ""; } ?></li>
```

or is this anyway to restrict custom fields in wordpress with edd content restriction? all these are custom fields that i want to restrics.

Comment: Your `do_shortcode()` call does not use proper PHP string syntax - PHP doesn't know what to do with `sample` or `php` because they look like keywords or identifiers (which they are not) and they're in locations in which PHP would expect a string operator (which they are not). Change the value to be a single string like `'[edd_restrict id="any"]sample php[/edd_restrict]'` or use "string concatenation" to merge multiple strings together, e.g. `'[edd_restrict id="any"]' . 'sample php' . '[/edd_restrict]'`.

Comment: Note that questions regarding third-party extensions are off-topic here; for the best advice regarding how to use EDD for your desired effect, you should enquire in the plugin's support channels

Comment: there is no support forum.. this is about changing shotcodes to php . is this off topic?

Comment: Executing a shortcode in a theme is certainly on-topic, which is what my first comment addressed. I don't think I understand what "changing a shortcode to php" means, however. And without knowing what the EDD plugin is or what it does or what "restricting" means in the context of that plugin, it's not clear what exactly you're trying to accomplish. There is no way to answer how to "restrict PHP" or "restrict custom fields" with the EDD plugin without having very specific knowledge about the EDD plugin itself. In short, it doesn't look like a solution can be provided with just core WP knowledge

Comment: forget edd. just can you tell me how run this shortcodes : [edd_restrict id="any"]sample restricted html or text[/edd_restrict]
in my single post theme for those php? isn't there a solution for using shortcodes into the theme?

Comment: Yes. You've pretty much got it right already - but `do_shortcodes()` expects to receive a single string as an argument, and in the code provided in your Question the PHP string syntax is wrong. Encapsulate the entire value in a single set of quotation marks, e.g. `'[edd_restrict id="any"]sample restricted html or text[/edd_restrict]'`

Comment: If you need to dynamically swap out the `sample restricted html or text` portion, use [PHP string concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336858/how-can-i-combine-two-strings-together-in-php)

Comment: i don't understand these codes. i just want a code that work for me. i dont know anything about coding

Comment: PHP sees text that surrounded by a set of matching quotes as a "string" - data consisting of a number of sequenced characters. In your code, the thing you're trying to pass to `do_shortcodes()` contains two separate strings - `'[edd_restrict id="any"]'` and `'[/edd_restrict]'` - and then some other stuff in between which PHP has no idea what to do with - `sample php`. `do_shortcode()` wants a single string, so you need to change it to `do_shortcode( '[edd_restrict id="any"]sample php[/edd_restrict]' );`

Comment: you mean this?
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[edd_restrict id="any"]sample php[/edd_restrict]' );?>

Comment: Yep! One set of `'`s there - so now it's just one string.

Comment: Fatal Error happens... should it use just for 1 php line?

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: this site experiencing technical difficulty

Comment: So, in production mode WordPress prevents full error messages from printing out in order to avoid exposing potentially sensitive information. The PHP error log should have a full error message recorded - but where that file is located and how you access it varies between web hosts. [`WP_DEBUG` constants](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/) placed in `wp-config.php` file can also help to get you the full message. That code in your comment looks fine to me though :/

Comment: <?php echo do_shortcode( '[edd_restrict id="any"]sample php[/edd_restrict]' );?>

this works in thh theme but just for text or html. not for a php command... i can not replace sample text with php in this way

Comment: This is where it becomes unclear what you're trying to accomplish when knowing nothing of the EDD restrict plugin. I briefly looked at their documentation and found no mention of it supporting restricting PHP. Do you mean that you want to use PHP to dynamically change `sample php` to a different string?

Comment: bro i don't know what i want in coding cause i don't know what is this. i just know what i want in function. as i said i want use this : <?php echo do_shortcode( '[edd_restrict id="any"]sample text[/edd_restrict]' );?>
but not for sample text! for the php codes (<?php if ...) i sent in main question...

Comment: Ahhh I think I understand now... you want to apply the shortcode to the output of that other PHP. I'll get an answer together for you here shortly. This all makes sense now - you're trying to show or hide download links based on whether or not someone has purchased a product

Comment: i hope there is a solution for this ...

Comment: yes. i want show or hide download link which are created with those php in my theme.

Answer (score 0):

Since `do_shortcode()` needs it's argument to be passed a string, instead of outputting the markup (e.g. `echo()`ing it), you should construct the markup as a string. There are many ways to do this. Below, I am using "string concatenation" (joining multiple strings into one) in order to add each relevant link to the same string which is stored in the `$download_links_markup` variable, then adding the shortcode tags on either side and passing the result into `do_shortcode()`:

```php
$download_links_markup = '<li>';

if( $href = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'download', true ) )
  $download_links_markup .= '<a href="' . $href . '"> دانلود با لینک مستقیم</a> ';

if( $href = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'download32', true ) )
  $download_links_markup .= '<a href="' . $href . '">لینک مستقیم نسخه 32bit / </a> ';

if( $href = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'download64', true ) )
  $download_links_markup .= '<a href="' . $href . '">لینک مستقیم نسخه 64bit </a> ';

if( $href = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'downloadwin', true ) )
  $download_links_markup .= '<a href="' . $href . '">دانلود نسخه ویندوز  </a> ';

$download_links_markup .= '</li>';

echo do_shortcode( '[edd_restrict id="any"]' . $download_links_markup . '[/edd_restrict]' );
```

I'm using some shortcuts in the `if()` statements, but the logic is more or less the same as the

```php
if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'download',true)!= ""){echo "<a href='".get_post_meta($post->ID, 'download',true)."' > دانلود با لینک مستقیم</a> ";} else { echo ""; }
```

conditionals used in your question.

Comment: didn't work. just shows the texts and some post links... not restricted and not showing right download links.

Comment: yes i did. it shows just texts

Comment: see. there is a div before these php codes. can we put it between shrotcodes instead of php? its like this : 
 <div class="dl">
<ul>
<li><?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'download',true)!= ""){echo "<a href='".get_post_meta($post->ID, 'download',true)."' > دانلود با لینک مستقیم</a> ";} else { echo ""; } ?>
<?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'download32',true)!= ""){echo "<a href='".get_post_meta($post->ID, 'download32',true)."'>لینک مستقیم نسخه 32bit / </a> ";} else { echo ""; } ?> 
and etc....

Comment: As far as I can test the code without having EDD or the restrict plugin installed, the code works - the string passed to `do_shortcode()` ends up as something looking like `'[edd_restrict id="any"]<li><a href="{...}">{...}</a><a href="{...}">{...}</a></li>[/edd_restrict]'`, with links appropriately left out if the corresponding post meta-data is not set. Adding or removing a `<div>` or whatever other markup changes is definitely an easy modification, but if it's still not restricting the links properly, you may need to find a dev who can take a closer look at the template code/EDD plugin

Comment: If you want to include more of the template code in the Question, or maybe stick it in a pastebin or something I can try to look a little more closely - but I'm not sure if I'll be able to locate the problem

Answer (score 0):

i've found this in plugin functions codes :

```
/**
 * Check if a post/page is restricted
 *
 * @since       1.0.0
 * @param       int $post_id the ID of the post to check
 * @return      bool True if post is restricted, false otherwise
 */
function edd_cr_is_restricted( $post_id ) {
    $restricted = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_edd_cr_restricted_to', true );

    return $restricted;
}
```

this should be restrict the whole post when i check it.

or found this :

```
array $restricted The items to which this is restricted
```